# Null java swing components

Tags: java, swing

I have created a gui using the simple netbeans designer when I try to access the components (such as a JPanel, or JLabel on the JPanel) I get a NullPointerException whenever I try and reference the components. When I run the program however the gui builds fine and the components are clearly there on the JFrame. Is there anything in particular I need to do to fix this and be able to reference the components?

For example I have a JPanel

```
private static JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
```

when I try and reference this in main such as

```
System.out.println(panelTop.getHeight());
```

I get the NullPointerException

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: If you're doing this in netbeans, make sure you are only trying to reference your components _after_ calling `initComponents()`.

Comment: A JPanel size (width, height) isn't set until after the JFrame pack.

Comment: @user1875195 is panelTop already visible, or